# Change tab and push view from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a method called handleLocalNotification in my AppDelegate that fires when my app gets a notification. I need it to switch to tab 0 in my UITabBarController which contains a UITableview. I then need it to push on the correct row of the tableview to show the record sent by the notification. All Controllers are created in the storyboard, so I have no references to them in the AppDelegate.

I've added to my AppDelegate.h:

```
@class MyListViewController;
@interface iS2MAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    MyListViewController *_listControl;

}
```

and for testing I'm just putting this in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method:

```
UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    tabb.selectedIndex = 0;
    _listControl = [tabb.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [_listControl.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

The tabBarController bit works as I can get it to load up on different tabs. The last 2 lines cause it to crash. Have I gone about this the correct way? Or do I need to use a different method?
The crash reason is:

> UINavigationController tableView]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i suggest to use `NSNotificationCenter` try to do it like this

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
  UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
  tabb.selectedIndex = 0;
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"localNotificationReceived" object:nil];
}
```

and in your viewController `viewDidLoad` :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(selectRows) name:@"localNotificationReceived" object:nil];
```

now you can use your tableView and do your stuff

```
-(void) selectRows
{
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0] animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
}
```

**To programmatically select a cell , this may do the job :**

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0];
[table selectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath 
                   animated:YES 
             scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
[table.delegate tableView:table didSelectRowAtIndexPath:selectedCellIndexPath];
```

because selectRowAtIndexPath will not fire the table delegate methods so you have to call with your self.

Comment: Thanks. That is a good way around it, however the notification observer isn't called when the app has been completely closed. I'm guessing the tableViewController hasn't been loaded by the time the postNotification is sent. If the app is just backgrounded it works.
Also, I made a mistake thinking selectRowAtIndexPath would actually press the row for me, but it just highlights it. Is there a method to make it press the particular row, so the prepareForSegue is called?

Comment: Excellent, that should fire the cell. What about when the app is first being loaded and the observer hasn't been setup when it's called? Can I get it to wait and make sure the ViewDidLoad has been called before firing the notification?

Comment: Well ... you can set a boolean value in `NSUserDefaults` if your app did receive local notification or not .. and check it in the view did load if it is yes do your stuff with the table view and reset the boolean to NO .. and if it is no just continue with the standard load.

Comment: Many Thanks. Got it all working with your suggestions.
Do you know if it's possible when didReceiveLocalNotification is called (Only called when app is loaded/backgrounded) to tell the difference if the app is actually in use on the screen, or just backgrounded?

Comment: No its been called in both cases if your app is active or not .. to take a different action to the both cases you will need to check the application state like this : `UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        // Application was in the background when notification was delivered.
    } else {

    }`

Comment: Can anyone help me out in this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17548967/push-view-from-inactive-class-iphone